# Squish not recognizing the dynamically changing object

Tags: testing, automation, record, squish

I am trying to automate an application (windows based). It was a record and playback. Squish is able to open and login to my application, but the moment when I am trying to click on a tab in the home screen it is saying unable to identify the object.

This is the piece of code:

```
mouseClick(waitForObject(": .ND - New Declaration_ListViewItem_18"));
```

In the end it stops and a new window pops up asking me to "picknewobject" when I pick the object that was not recognized, I see that the objects id has changed dynamically.
eg: "ND - New Declaration_ListViewItem_18" changes to "ND - New Declaration_ListViewItem_19" and so forth.

Comment: I think you`ll find your answer here: http://blog.froglogic.com/2014/08/squish-tip-of-the-week-how-to-find-and-use-dynamic-objects/

Comment: or, your tab has a parent object. read the children of that object, and compare their names with the desired one)

Answer (score 0):

The strings starting with a colon (`:`) passed to `waitForObject`, such as `: .ND - New Declaration_ListViewItem_18`, have no meaning by themselves. They are just symbolic identifiers (called "symbolic names" in Squish) which are used to perform a lookup in the so-called object map. The object map associates each symbolic name with a "real name", and that real name actually defines the properties by which an object is identified.

So if you find that Squish does not re-use an existing (and supposedly matching) name but rather generates a new name, you need to look at the object map and check the real names associated with `: .ND - New Declaration_ListViewItem_18` and `: .ND - New Declaration_ListViewItem_19`; it may be that the real names involve some volatile property, e.g. a property which changes its value on every run of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when we have run into this, it is because we are getting a new object each time we try to access the object in a particular test run. Each of these new objects have the same properties.  So, Squish is trying to reference the subsequent instances with an "occurrence='n'" property.

A simple way to solve this issue reliably is to use a parent object (something stable in the app that is not getting instantiated and trashed) and then traverse the component hierarchy of the parent object by name (hopefully the component you're interacting with has a unique name).

You can create a function to do this...

My experience is Squish for Java on Linux using JavaScript as a test language.  So, I'm not sure my script examples will help.  But, we have an "aut" namespace that we have created and we put a bunch of different functions in that namespace that know how to traverse the Java component hierarchy (up and down through the hierarchy) to find object by name, type, text, etc.

```
/** javascript **/
let listItemAncestor = findObject(":SomeSymbolicNameForAncestor");
let declarationListItem = aut.fetchDescendantByName(listItemAncestor, "NewDeclarationListItem");
mouseClick(waitForObject(delarationListItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you spy the object and use those properties to perform the mouse click event. It becomes easy to maintain the tests and you can makes the test more robust by using wild card.

Eg:

startApplication("Addressbook")

mouseClick("{type='MenuItem' text?='File'}")

Refer https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/5.1/rg-namelookup.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is guarenteed that this dynamic object appears at the same pont in the object hierarchy, you can capture a unique object at the upper level and loop down to the position of your dynamic object.

For example, if your dynamic object appears as the second object of a panel (and panel can be identified uniquley) then (using JavaScript),

```
var myPanel = waitForObject(yourPanelObjectName);
var myPanel_children = object.children(myPanel);
var myDynamicObject = myPanel_children[1];
```

You may also use objet.parent() instead, if you can identify a unique object below the dynamic object in the hierarchy.